# How to debug in a different locale in VS2017

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, locale

I have a nasty bug which manifests itself only when I run my C# program on a non-english Windows. It is a conversion from double to string (I get commas instead of dots on some values we shouldn't localize). In order to test the fix (i.e. applying `InvariantLocale` everywhere) I need to build the executable and run it on a non-english VM, it's very time consuming.

My question is: is it possible to debug inside VS2017 pretending to be on a non-english Windows environment? (let's say for example a Dutch Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a utility class for setting the language:

```
public static class LanguageSetter
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern ushort SetThreadUILanguage(ushort _languageId);

    public static void SetLanguage(string uiLanguage)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(uiLanguage);
        SetThreadUILanguage((ushort) Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(uiLanguage);
    }
}
```

Just call it with `LanguageSetter.SetLanguage("nl-NL");`

If you use WPF, add another line at the end of that function:
`FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag)));`

Comment: If I call that function on a given thread do all the other child threads inherit the same locale?

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini you call that early in `static Main()`. Note that the `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` is not available in older versions of .Net framework, and newly generated threads would then inherit their culture from the OS.